# Logical error in selecting rows with correct output

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I understand the basics but I am new to DBMSs and I'm learning in a course.

Here is the assignment question:

> Write a query to display the number of sales that were made in the last 40 months with the below table:
>
> ```
> SALEID  SID SLDATE
> 1001    1   01-JAN-14
> 1002    5   02-JAN-14
> 1003    4   01-FEB-14
> 1004    1   01-MAR-14
> 1005    2   01-FEB-14
> 1006    1   01-JUN-15
> ```

My query is:

```
select count(sldate) as sale_count
from sale
where sldate >= add_months(sysdate, -40)
```

The output expected and that I get is:

```
SALE_COUNT
0
```

But I get an error message:

> Error: Your query output matches expected result, but there are logical errors.

I'm not sure where I got the logic wrong.

Comment: We can't tell you why Infy is saying that unfortunately. The message suggests it's running your code and some baseline version of its own and comparing the results, but also somehow comparing the actual code. I'd guess it might be expecting you to use `trunc(sysdate, 'MM')` or something, but might be looking at the column alias, or... who knows. We just can't tell I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. May be Infy is wrong this time. If there's no logic errors from SQL perspective, then I'm happy :)

Answer (score 1):

The 'last 40 months' is ambiguous.

There are several interpretation of 'what does last n months from date x mean' and oracle''s add_months does not have monopoly on that (in fact most people would say it doesn't work as expected, just wait till the 30.06 and ask somebody 'what was the date a month ago' :) )

Imagine today is 20 of april.
Does 'last month' include 15, 20, 21, or 25 of march? 
Does it include 02 of april? 
That depends, someone could say that 'last month' is from 21 of march to 20 of april.
Someone could say, that 'last month' from 01.03 to today.
Someone could say, that 'last month' starts from 01.04.
Someone could say, that 'last month' means whole march, but not a single day of april.

It gets even trickier when 'today' is close to the end of the month, especially in march.

Don't be hard on yourself just because you couldn't read mind of someone who wrote the assignment ;)

I've wrote a query showing how different approches might yield different results.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temp_can_subst_interval_months(p_date date, p_n_of_months number) RETURN NUMBER AS
V_date DATE;
BEGIN
    V_Date := p_date - (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(p_n_of_months, 'month'));
    RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;


with all_days as (
   select to_date('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (level - 1) as d
     from dual
    connect by level < 1462

),
all_days_2 as (
select d date_of_query_being_run,
       add_months(d, -40)as min_date_your_approach,
       add_months(d, -40) + 1 as min_date_your_approach_2, -- same, but exclude the first day
       trunc(add_months(d, -40), 'mm') as min_date_whole_month,
       case when temp_can_subst_interval_months(d, 40) = 1 then
         d - (interval '40' month)
       else null
       end as min_date_interval_approach
  from all_days ad
 order by ad.d
)
select ads.*
  from all_days_2 ads
  ;
```

The most interesting results are when your approach differs from interval approach:

```
1 (sysdate) 2 (yours)   3           4           5 (interval)
31.01.2016  30.09.2012  01.10.2012  01.09.2012  
29.02.2016  31.10.2012  01.11.2012  01.10.2012  29.10.2012
31.03.2016  30.11.2012  01.12.2012  01.11.2012  
30.04.2016  31.12.2012  01.01.2013  01.12.2012  30.12.2012
29.06.2016  28.02.2013  01.03.2013  01.02.2013  
30.06.2016  28.02.2013  01.03.2013  01.02.2013  
31.08.2016  30.04.2013  01.05.2013  01.04.2013  
30.09.2016  31.05.2013  01.06.2013  01.05.2013  30.05.2013
31.10.2016  30.06.2013  01.07.2013  01.06.2013  
30.11.2016  31.07.2013  01.08.2013  01.07.2013  30.07.2013
31.01.2017  30.09.2013  01.10.2013  01.09.2013  
28.02.2017  31.10.2013  01.11.2013  01.10.2013  28.10.2013
31.03.2017  30.11.2013  01.12.2013  01.11.2013  
30.04.2017  31.12.2013  01.01.2014  01.12.2013  30.12.2013
29.06.2017  28.02.2014  01.03.2014  01.02.2014  
30.06.2017  28.02.2014  01.03.2014  01.02.2014  
31.08.2017  30.04.2014  01.05.2014  01.04.2014  
30.09.2017  31.05.2014  01.06.2014  01.05.2014  30.05.2014
31.10.2017  30.06.2014  01.07.2014  01.06.2014  
30.11.2017  31.07.2014  01.08.2014  01.07.2014  30.07.2014
31.01.2018  30.09.2014  01.10.2014  01.09.2014  
28.02.2018  31.10.2014  01.11.2014  01.10.2014  28.10.2014
31.03.2018  30.11.2014  01.12.2014  01.11.2014  
30.04.2018  31.12.2014  01.01.2015  01.12.2014  30.12.2014
29.06.2018  28.02.2015  01.03.2015  01.02.2015  
30.06.2018  28.02.2015  01.03.2015  01.02.2015  
31.08.2018  30.04.2015  01.05.2015  01.04.2015  
30.09.2018  31.05.2015  01.06.2015  01.05.2015  30.05.2015
31.10.2018  30.06.2015  01.07.2015  01.06.2015  
30.11.2018  31.07.2015  01.08.2015  01.07.2015  30.07.2015
31.01.2019  30.09.2015  01.10.2015  01.09.2015  
28.02.2019  31.10.2015  01.11.2015  01.10.2015  28.10.2015
31.03.2019  30.11.2015  01.12.2015  01.11.2015  
30.04.2019  31.12.2015  01.01.2016  01.12.2015  30.12.2015
30.06.2019  29.02.2016  01.03.2016  01.02.2016  
31.08.2019  30.04.2016  01.05.2016  01.04.2016  
30.09.2019  31.05.2016  01.06.2016  01.05.2016  30.05.2016
31.10.2019  30.06.2016  01.07.2016  01.06.2016  
30.11.2019  31.07.2016  01.08.2016  01.07.2016  30.07.2016
```

Side note:
Maybe the table contains something like 'future expected sales' and they want you to filter out dates later than sysdate ;)?